# Does the bonus action from spiritual weapon break invisibility?

Tags: spells, invisibility

Suppose a character casts Spiritual Weapon one round, then casts invisibility the following round. Does using the bonus action from spiritual weapon to attack count as making an attack for the sake of ending the invisibility spell?

Comment: Hi vexxed, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and check out [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9185/48759) for other places you can find help, or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping people). Before we can answer this, we need to know what system and edition you are playing. The best way to do this is to [edit] in the appropriate system tag (e.g. [tag:dnd-5e]). Good luck and happy gaming!